# Recovery of Bandlimited Signals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing

Let $\Omega > 0$ and denote by $\mathcal{B}_\Omega$ the subspace of $L^2(\Bbb R)$ consisting of signals that are bandlimited to $(-\Omega, \Omega)$.  Denote $\mathcal{L}_{\Omega} : L^2(\Bbb R) \rightarrow L^2(\Bbb R)$ the ideal lowpass filter that projects signals $x \in L^2(\Bbb R)$ into $\mathcal{B}_\Omega$: i.e., $\mathcal{L}_\Omega$ takes $x$ to the signal $y$ with

\begin{equation}
\hat{y} =\begin{cases}
    \hat{x} & \text{for } |\omega| < \Omega\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

A function $\gamma: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ is monotone increasing if $\gamma (t_2) > \gamma (t_1)$.  The companding of a signal $x: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ by $\gamma$ is the signal $[\gamma \circ  x](t) = \gamma(x(t))$.

1. Denote $u(t) = sinc(2\Omega t)$.  Find an explicit expression of $\mathcal{L}_\Omega (u)(t)$.
2. If $x \in \mathcal{B}_\Omega$ and $\gamma$ is monotone increasing, then $\gamma \circ x$ is generally not bandlimited.  In particular, $\mathcal{L}_\Omega (\gamma \circ x) \neq \gamma \circ x$.  Suppose $x_1, x_2 \in \mathcal{B}_\Omega$ and $\mathcal{L}_\Omega (\gamma \circ x_1) = (\gamma \circ x_2)$.  Show that $x_1 = x_2$ almost everywhere on $\Bbb R$.

---

**My Attempt/Input**

So I know this is regarding the recovery of bandlimited signals after companding and running through a low pass filter.

For the first part,  this is essentially asking for an expression for when the sinc function is run through the low pass filter, correct?  But the frequency of the sinc function doesn't change so wouldn't the whole signal go through?

As for the second part, I know I start with the integral of the product of $(x_1 - x_2)$ with $(\gamma \circ x_1 - \gamma \circ x_2)$ but not sure how to go about it.

Comment: the frequency of $\operatorname{sinc}$?

Comment: Actually, the sinc function is just a LPF, correct?

Comment: Convolution with a sinc function of infinite length is an ideal brick wall (boxcar, whatever) LPF. If it's written as $\operatorname{sinc}(\pi Bx)$, then the cut off frequencies of the filter will be $\pm B/2$. I am afraid that the rest of your question has too much analysis-style mumbojumbo in it for me to makes heads or tails of.

Comment: Nicely phrased question. For the 1st part, yes, trivially. $\mathcal{L}_{\Omega}$, being an orthogonal projection, has the property that $\mathcal{L}_{\Omega} x = x$ for any bandlimited $x$.